# NSDateFormatterShortStyle - How do I get short date for any region and language in iOS?

Tags: ios, date, localization

I need to format a date to have 2 digit month, day, and year.  I have a problem with dates on devices set to language France region France.  I am using the code below to test:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *shortDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@" Short Date is %@",shortDate);
```

When region on device is set to United States, I get the expected result 4/22/14  however, if I set the region to France I get 22/04/2014 - with a 4 digit year.  The Apple docs indicate that NSDateFormatterShortStyle "typically" formats to a 2 digit year but I have a feeling that I am dealing with an exception.  Can anyone explain what is going on and how I might consistently format the dates into a DD/MM/YY format that is localized?

P.S. In order to see this behavior on the simulator you need to reset it and then set the language and region to French and France.

Thanks, Joseph

Comment: You need to decide what is more important, using the accepted "short" style for a given locale which may or may not have a 2-digit year, or forcing users to see a format they don't normally use. If you want to convert `dd/MM/yy` into the proper order for a given locale, look at `NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`.

Comment: Thank you. I am now successfully "forcing users to see a format they don't normally use" - but I feel awful about it.